# Filter tag synonyms I have enough rep for voting

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

The [list of tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) can be pretty long.

On most of them I can't vote because I do not have enough rep on the tag.

Please add a filter checkbox to the page so I can view only synonyms I actually can vote on.

Comment: I was not aware that Stack Exchange did requests :P